# hide chekbox, highlight selected pitures

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, label

I would like to hide the chekboxes in my from and replace them with pictures. At the moment i already have the pictures but i would also like to hide the check3boxes themself. if one of the pictures gets selected, it should get a highlighted border. I would be really glad for any help

here's my current form code

```
    <form type="post" action="photoselection.php">
            <div id="photowrapper">

                <div class="photo">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="bild1">
                    <label class="label_item" for="rbild1"><img src="bild1.jpg"/></label>
                </div>
                <div class="photo">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="bild2" id="rbild2">
                    <label class="label_item" for="rbild2"><img src="bild2.jpg"/></label>
                </div>
                <div class="photo">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="bild3" id="rbild3">
                    <label class="label_item" for="rbild3"><img src="bild3.jpg"/></label>
                </div>
                <div class="photo">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="bild4" id="rbild4">
                    <label class="label_item" for="rbild4"><img src="bild4.jpg"/></label>
                </div>
                <div class="photo">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="bild5" id="rbild5">
                    <label class="label_item" for="rbild5"><img src="bild5.jpg"/></label>
                </div>
                <div class="photo">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="bild6" id="rbild2">
                    <label class="label_item" for="rbild2"><img src="bild2.jpg"/></label>
                <Input type = "Submit" Name = "Submit" VALUE = "Bild anzeigen">
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: your missing a tag.  I think `javascript` or `jQuery` can do what you want.

Comment: What roullie said, I'd recommend jQuery, one way of doing it would be do use `$('.checkbox').click(function() {` and then use `this.hide();` - Or something along those lines. (I'd recommend applying a class for the jQuery watcher and then use `this` to identify the checkbox calling/triggering the jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can do it using CSS
<style> 

.photo > input{
display:none;
}

.photo > input:checked + label > img{
border: 3px solid black;
}

</style>
```

Hope it should work

Comment: thanks mate! that worked perfect, it's exactely what i wanted

Comment: If, it worked fine, please mark the answer as Accepted, so that next time If someone has same prob, he knows Which answer he can directly use.

Comment: sure,sorry was my first question on here, didn't think about doing that. But it's done now

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment (and as @roullie mentioned), one way to do it is with jQuery / JS, a simple way to hide the checkboxes would be to do it like this:

jQuery example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".checkbox" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).hide();
    });
});
```

And then apply the checkbox class to any of the checkboxes you want to hide when a image is shown.

This can also be used to show the checkbox again or add some other logic to be executed when the image is shown.

Comment: thanks but the way danton mentioned, is actually way easier for me

Comment: @Econ Sure :) Remember to mark his question as "Accepted" if it did the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use your image as background-image and with the help of a wrapper you can hide the checkbox completly. Works also with radio buttons (with a slight addition)

```
//HTML
<div class="checkbox">
    <input id="check" value="" name="check" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
    <label for="check"></label>
</div>

//CSS:
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent url("https://placehold.it/100x50/4DA61F") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    border: 1px solid darkred;
    background: transparent url("https://placehold.it/100x50/F3C914") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_Gr/L60fzxp3/)**

---

Here a second solution with a inline image:

```
//HTML
<div class="checkbox">
    <input id="check" value="" name="check" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="check">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/100x50/deff00" alt=""/>
    </label>
</div>

//CSS
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0;
    border: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_Gr/L60fzxp3/2/)**